# RSpec: why included modules make available only methods, but not constants?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a module including constants that I want to use in the unit tests across a test suite.

What I don't understand is why, if I include the module, constants are not available, but methods (if I add any to the module) are.

Example:

```rb
module Namespace
  module Constants
    K = 1
    def mymethod; end
  end
end

describe Namespace::Subject do
  include Namespace::Constants
  context "Context" do
    it "should execute" do
      mymethod # succeeds
      K        # fails
    end
  end
end
```

The same principle works in a console:

```rb
2.5.5 :008 > include Namespace::Constants
 => Object 
2.5.5 :010 > K
 => 1
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this, because it's just how it works in Ruby (it's not specific to RSpec in any way). You can access the constant with `Namespace::Constants::K`.

Comment: @katafrakt that's not correct. if you execute in an irb session `include Namespace::Constants; K`, it will print `K`'s value.

Answer (score -1):

Constants defined within a namespace can be called by prefacing the constants from within the namespace.  Inheritance is at the level of which it is defined. When you include the methods in a new module or class they can be called the object level they are defined at.

The reason `K` worked inside Ruby console is that you included them at the default or global scope.  If you had done this for example, you would get a different result.

```rb
class A
  include Namespace::Constants
end

K
NameError: uninitialized constant K
A::K
=>1

a = A.new

a.class::K
=>1
```

Here's a spec that may also explain it

```rb
require 'pry'

module Namespace
  module Constants
    def mymethod; end
    K = 1
  end
end

module Namespace
  module Subject
    include Namespace::Constants
  end
end

class A
  include Namespace::Constants
end

describe Namespace::Subject do
  describe 'Inherited Constants' do
    it 'is defined module level' do
      # Check if K is defined at the class level
      expect(Namespace::Subject.const_get(:K)).to eq(1)
      expect(Namespace::Subject::K).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end

describe A do
  describe 'instance methods' do
    it 'defines mymethod' do
      a = A.new
      expect(a).to respond_to(:mymethod)
    end
  end
  describe 'inherits' do
    it 'inherits class definitions' do
      expect(A::K).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end

describe 'Global Scope'  do
  it 'K is not defined' do
    include Namespace::Constants
    begin
      K
    rescue NameError => e
      puts e
    end
  end
end
```

Hopefully this illustrates the way inheritance works in Ruby. The issue you're facing has nothing to do with Rspec itself.